# Why do clouds depolarize skylight?

Tags: electromagnetism, optics

Skylight is polarized, essentially because of Rayleigh scattering. Rayleigh scattering occurs for particle sizes much smaller than the wavelength of incident light. This is the case of air molecules, but probably not the case of water droplets in clouds, for which Mie scattering would take over.

But as far as I know, Mie scattering also produces polarised light, so why do clouds depolarize skylight?

Comment: I suspect that it is related to the fact that when a light beam is reflected multiple times by mirrors into directions that lie outside a plane, the polarization is rotated.  In a cloud, light undergoes multiple scatterings in many random directions, so its polaruzation will be randomized.